# Django : How can I prepare datasets in database before deploying web application?

Tags: django, deployment, django-deployment

I created e-commerce web application using `Django`.

Before I deploy my application ver2, I have to create items (datas) to sell. 
(ver1 is running now)

Because of `one-to-many`, `many-to-many` relations among the models, it is much easier to create item datas via `django-admin` page than other methods.

Problem is though, if I run this application on production server, it can be accessed through internet even though all items are not ready!!

How can I deal with it?

Comment: If you have some set of data in your localdevelopment server, you can take a dump of the same and dump in your prod server.

Comment: @BipulJain local store data file in server itself, but production use AWS s3